# For all non-zero vectors v in R^n, the non-zero vector u is orthogonal to what?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a multiple choice question:

```
For all non-zero vectors v in R^n, the non-zero vector u is orthogonal to:

(a) projv(u)
(b) v − proju(v)
(c) v + proju(v)
(d) proju(v)
```

My intuition tells me that it is b but i would like to hear other opinions.

Comment: Well, your intution is right. Just try and google it, you will get loads of pictures, such as this- http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/MOW/vectors/vectors-10/v-10-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this by sheer algebra: $$u\cdot (v-\text{proj}_u{v})=u\cdot\left(v-\left(\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}\right)u\right)=u\cdot v-u\cdot v=0$$